# Laravel API ajax request not being authenticated

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-8

We are planning to use ajax to `post` some data. This is our code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "{{route('something.someevent')}}",
  data: {
    _token: _token
  },
  success: function(o) {
    console.log(o);
  },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

The problem is we are getting

> [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 133ms]

If we remove the `$this->middleware('auth');` on the construct, we are are able to receive the data. The user is actually **logged in**.

How to make the API be authenticated same with the app? Thanks is advance

Comment: Where doy ou get the token from? Are you using laravel passport?

Comment: @Aless55 var _token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");

Comment: The Laravel authentication. Im not sure if thats passport.

Answer (score 2):

We add the token as a header to all of our ajax requests as opposed to including it inside the body.

You can add the below to a single ajax request.

```
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
```

Alternatively, if you want the header to automatically get injected to every ajax request you make you can define this in a global script somewhere.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```